# How do I prevent reloading from undoing my .innerHTML action?

Tags: javascript

I have made a simple website for my school's coding club and it is working fine except for the one little piece of javascript on the index page. This javascript is just a simple little randomizer for who brings the snack the next week. However, after the program has run, and the name pops up if you reload the name doesn't save. I've tried saving it to localStorage and accessing it but it isn't helping. Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Coding Club</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="downloads.html">Downloads</a></li>
  <li><a href="websites.html">Websites</a></li>
  <li><a href="snackslist.html">Snacks</a></li>
</ul>
  <h1>Coding Club</h1>
  <h2>Welcome!</h2>
  <p>Welcome to the Heritage Coding Club website. Here you can find information about programs that you can keep, useful downloads, websites, and favorite snacks!</p>
  <h2 id="snack">Next Week's Snack Bringer is:</h2>
<div id="random">
  <button onclick="start()">Randomize!</button>
</div>
</body>
<script>
var names = ["Dylan", "David", "Sparsh", "Ananya", "Anna", "Anusha", "Brandon", "Justin", "Natasha and Neil", "Rishab", "Shannon", "Ms. Wolek"];
function start() {
  var n = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)];
  if(n == "Natasha and Neil") {
  document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = "Next Week's Snack Bringers are: Natasha and Neil";
}else{
  document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = "Next Week's Snack Bringer is: " + n;
}}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to save it for a limited time?

Comment: I would like to save it until the button is clicked again

Comment: I think that local storage is perfect for this purpose

Comment: That's what I thought but after the reload the website didn't update but stayed blank. It saved and pulled from local storage but never updated the page

Comment: Where did you put the code for pulling from the storage and updating the page?

Comment: Here is the code for localStorage

Comment: function start() {
  var n = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)];
  if(n == "Natasha and Neil") {
  localStorage.setItem("snackname", "Next Week's Snack Bringers are: Natasha and Neil");
  document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("snackname");
}else{
  localStorage.setItem("snackname", "Next Week's Snack Bringer is " + n);
  document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("snackname");
}}

Comment: If you want to begin storing large amount of data, you should look at using a server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the localStorage Object, Like This :

```
var names = ["Dylan", "David", "Sparsh", "Ananya", "Anna", "Anusha", "Brandon", "Justin", "Natasha and Neil", "Rishab", "Shannon", "Ms. Wolek"];

// The randomize button click event used to be start()
function randomize(){
  var n = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)];
  setName(n);

}

function setName(n)
{ 
  // Simple Method to add the name to the element
  if (n == "Natasha and Neil") {
    document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = "Next Week's Snack Bringers are: Natasha and Neil";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = "Next Week's Snack Bringer is: " + n;
  }
  save(n);
}

function save(n)
{
  // Saving to the storage
  localStorage.setItem('name', n);
}

// For When the page loads
window.onload = function(){

  // If there is something in the storage we gonna get it else we do nothing.
  var n = localStorage.getItem('name');
  if (n) 
  {
    setName(n);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Coding Club</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="downloads.html">Downloads</a></li>
  <li><a href="websites.html">Websites</a></li>
  <li><a href="snackslist.html">Snacks</a></li>
</ul>
  <h1>Coding Club</h1>
  <h2>Welcome!</h2>
  <p>Welcome to the Heritage Coding Club website. Here you can find information about programs that you can keep, useful downloads, websites, and favorite snacks!</p>
  <h2 id="snack">Next Week's Snack Bringer is:</h2>
<div id="random">
  <button onclick="start()">Randomize!</button>
</div>
</body>
<script>
var names = ["Dylan", "David", "Sparsh", "Ananya", "Anna", "Anusha", "Brandon", "Justin", "Natasha and Neil", "Rishab", "Shannon", "Ms. Wolek"];
function start() {
  var n = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)];
localStorage.name=n;
  if(n == "Natasha and Neil") {
  document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = "Next Week's Snack Bringers are: Natasha and Neil";
}else{
  document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = "Next Week's Snack Bringer is: " + n;
}}

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
n=localStorage.name;
    if(n == "Natasha and Neil") {
  document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = "Next Week's Snack Bringers are: Natasha and Neil";
}else{
  document.getElementById("snack").innerHTML = "Next Week's Snack Bringer is: " + n;
}
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
</script>
</html>
```

What you do is save the name when you click the button and when the page reload all the code out of the start function is executed so the text is updated with the last name

P.S. sorry for the indentation but i'm using the phone